# Making a Belt of Negative Dexterity

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting, ability-scores

So in my group there is a PC who has a questionable background and therefore we don't exactly trust him. I am looking for a way to set up a contingency in case he ever betrays us, and I think I know what I want, but can't figure out how much it would cost to create.

What I want to create is a Belt of Incredible Dexterity +4 that acts as normal until the command word is spoken, then the bonus gets removed and replaced with a negative modifier instead (So a Belt of Gracelessness -4). The +4 bonus has a base cost of 16000, and looking at [the magic item creation page](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) it appears adding a command word should add some price, but I can't figure out if it would be based on the command word or the continuous application of touch of gracelessness or the multiple different abilities price, or if its a sum of all three

So to specify, my question is: How much would a cursed belt of incredible dexterity +4 cost to create with the curse being the ability to switch the bonus to a penalty?

Comment: Is your GM aware and on-board with you using custom magic item creation?

Comment: Yes, they are onboard with it. We just didn't know what a reasonable cost for this item would be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You will need to use the rules for creating a cursed item

Generally speaking, cursed items trigger and fail the first time they are used in a dangerous situation or alternatively, once activated, they cannot be deactivated without appropriate removal. You will also require access to the [*bestow curse*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bestow-curse/) spell as one of the item's prerequisite for crafting it. The rules for what you are looking for can be found under [Cursed Items](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items/) under the section: [Opposite Effect or Target](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items/#Opposite_Effect_or_Target).

For example the item [Gauntlets of Fumbling](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items/#TOC-Gauntlets-of-Fumbling) does what you are asking for but has no trigger word.

The pricing mechanic is appropriately detailed and marked on the table below the linked section above:

> - 90% of the normal price for the beneficial effect the item duplicates in addition to its curse or when its curse is not active.

Initial Effect (90%) + Opposite Effect (50%) + Command Word (?) = 140% (+?%) cost of the belt you are trying to create.